# Android camera-intent save image and display in imageView FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I'm trying to put a recently taken image inside an imageView. I get the right path and the image is there but i end up in the FileNotFoundException anyway. Anyone knows what seams to be the problem?

```
else if (requestCode == CAMERA_RESULT) {

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath(), pictureName.toString());
            Log.d("MainActivity", file.toString()); // It's the right filePath
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);


            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {

                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                Log.d("MainActivity", bitmap.toString());

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

This is another try i'v made

```
else if (requestCode == CAMERA_RESULT) {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath(), pictureName.toString());
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        InputStream inputStream;
        try {
            inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), options);
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            Log.d("MainActivity", uri.toString());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

}